# How to fix npm repository, when Validation Error occurs?

Tags: node.js, npm

I encountered a problem when building a project with angular.
To build, I use:

```
npm install
```

To run, I use:

```
npm install
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 Module build failed: Validation Error

URL Loader Invalid Options

options['name'] should NOT have additional properties options.limit should be number

 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:412-465  @ ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./src/styles.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 Module build failed: Validation Error

URL Loader Invalid Options

options['name'] should NOT have additional properties options.limit should be number

 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:495-547  @ ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./src/styles.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 Module build failed: Validation Error

URL Loader Invalid Options

options['name'] should NOT have additional properties options.limit should be number

 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:576-627  @ ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./src/styles.scss
```

I tried buid this on Windows 10, and on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
npm -v
6.4.1
node -v
v10.14.2
```

dependencies stored in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.4",
    "@types/uuid": "3.4.4",
    "blueimp-load-image": "2.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "exif-js": "2.3.0",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "mydatepicker": "2.6.1",
    "ngx-quill": "1.6.0",
    "popper.js": "1.12.5",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.2",
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "license-webpack-plugin": "1.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "5.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "url-loader": "0.6.0",
    "webpack": "~3.6.0",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.7.1"
  }
```

Probably some of these libraries are not used, but I do not want to delete them. Should I update some of them?

Comment: I try your package.json on CodeSanbox and it working https://codesandbox.io/s/m37jpy8p8x. You maybe try delete `package-lock.json` and `npm intall` again

Comment: I have cloned this repository with empty packages-lock.json and without node_modules.

Comment: Is it working? With current your project, please delete `package-lock.json` and `npm install`. If it isn't still working, please delete `node_modules` and try again. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error occurred during building and I did not see it. The error was connected with old version with font-awesome.